# Calculate fix ratio for every point in different mobile devises

Tags: android, cordova, touch, resolution

I want to have a fix ratio for every points in the display so I can identify them and do the proper action.
I have an xml file that shows me what to do when I got touch at the specific point like:

```
<page num="1">
    <touch coordinate_x="3/4" coordinate_y="1/4">
        <sound>/Sounds/BTSP/p1/1.wav</sound>
    </touch>
</page>
```

I should detect(calculate) those x and y coordinate ratio.
I detect touches using this technique:

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", Clicked, false);
function Clicked(){
    var x = event.touches[0].pageX;
    var y = event.touches[0].pageY;
    alert(x+"::::"+y);
    }
```

but I should divide these x and y that I get from event.touches by something(display resolution) that gives me some unique numbers.
what do you suggest?

Comment: use percentage. It's the logical way.!

Comment: but event.touches returns number not percentage.
I should divide these numbers by something to reach percentage.

Comment: the parent view height and width. Every view have a getWidth and getHeight methods.